# Is correct this definition of family?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, reference-request

Let $A$ be a set and let $I$ be a non-empty set. Every application $f:I\to A$ is said to be a family of elements of $A$ with indices in I. Let us posit, for every $i \in $I$, f(i)=f_i$. Then the family is denoted by the symbol $(f_i)_{i\in I}$.

> Then I can denote "family" when the number representing the index of the element in the set $i$ corresponds to the element to which to apply $f$?

On which book can I find the correct and comprehensive explanation of the notion "family", for a math undergraduate?

Comment: The notion familiy usally refers to a collection of sets. I think this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_of_sets provides a good overview.

Comment: For me "$(A_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of sets" means that I am given a pair $(I,A)$, where $I$ is a set and $A$ is the graph of a function whose codomain is a set of sets (of course the function is not unique).

Comment: I do not understand why your question was closed. Note that there is a difference between $(f_i)_{i∈I}$ and $\{f_i\}_{i∈I}$. The first one is technically a function as you cited, and allows the possibility that $f_i = f_j$ for some $i ≠ j$, which means that the $i$-th and $j$-th element in the family are identical. The second one is just a set, and so of course cannot have duplicate elements. In fact, the second one is exactly the range of the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of books have descriptions of families for different contexts:

- *Naive Set Theory* By Paul Halmos has a chapter on a naive (non-axiomatic) description of families in familiar and formal language.
- *On Families of Sets Represented in Theories* By Hilary Putnam is an entire book dedicated to families of sets. I don't know your level of math education so I'm unsure if this is appropriate, but, you know.
- Most books on set theory by most authors. These books probably cover families in a correct and comprehensive explanation. You can google "book on set theory pdf" and the specific book will pop up probably.

My explanation: Consider a set of subsets, $\mathcal{F}$. We call  $\mathcal{F}$ a family of sets over $$\bigcup_{F \in \mathcal{F}} F$$
Moreover, we may index with $i \in I$ for $F_i \in \mathcal{F}$, to distinguish each element of $\mathcal{F}$. In this way, a family $\mathcal{F}$ is a set of subsets of $\bigcup_{F \in \mathcal{F}} F$.

> Then I can denote "family" when the number representing the index of the element in the set i
> corresponds to the element to which to apply f
> ?

Yes. I don't think many will argue if you don't define $f: I \rightarrow A$ and instead just write $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$. However, The notation you use, $\{f_i\}_{i \in I}$ is equivalent.